# QWidget transparent background (but not the children)

Tags: qt, background, qwidget

I have a QWidget that contains a `QPixmap` and a `QComboxBox` in its Layout. I would like to set the background of the widget transparent (but I want to show the `QPixmap` and the `QComboBox` normally). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all well-explained in QWidget documentation:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering

Comment: both links are dead, which is the reason why answers should not just contain links but the relevant information itself.

Comment: I agree that is a problem. However the information asked for here is not very specific and the documentation is explaining it very well. No need to repeat it here. I updated the link to the documentation.

Comment: The explanation does not really help or work, though.
I added a QGraphicsView to a transparent widget, but despite setting the graphics view's Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen attribute, it remains to appear as transparent as the widget it is in.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the attribute

```
widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
```

[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) :

> Indicates that the widget has no background, i.e. when the widget
>   receives paint events, the background is not automatically repainted.
>   Note: Unlike WA_OpaquePaintEvent, newly exposed areas are never filled
>   with the background (e.g., after showing a window for the first time
>   the user can see "through" it until the application processes the
>   paint events). This flag is set or cleared by the widget's author.