# QFrame with background image and otherwise transparent background

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qframe

I am making a desktop carousel app. There I need to show image widgets, which might contain other sub-widgets as well. For that I am using a `QFrame` with the required image as background. Here is the image I am trying to use: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I3aG.jpg). What I want is that only the image shows up, no background image or anything shows up as well, so to the user it looks like just the image. Here is my code:

```
setGeometry(QRect(100, 20, 325,400));
setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel);
setStyleSheet("QFrame#ImageFrame { background-color: transparent; background: url(:icon/ipad-skin); }");
setAutoFillBackground(false);
```

However, I am getting this as a result:

[image]

I tried this as well (obtained from [here](http://ahmadferdous.blogspot.in/2009/05/qt-set-background-image-of-custom.html)) (and removing the stylesheet):

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p)
{
    QPainter* pPainter = new QPainter(this);
    pPainter->drawPixmap(rect(), QPixmap(":icon/newskin.png"));
    delete pPainter;
    QWidget::paintEvent(p);
}
```

Nothing different, the exact same result. The greyness of the background still shows.

How do I make the grey background of the `QFrame` go and display only the image (the dimensions I am setting are the same as the image)?

P.S I am aware that similar questions hve been answered here: [QWidget transparent background (but not the children)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688750/qwidget-transparent-background-but-not-the-children), and here: [Frameless and transparent window qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316710/frameless-and-transparent-window-qt5) but these doesn't solve my problem. The last solution makes my QFrame look like this:

[image]

The QFrame now comes with a title bar which is anything but what I wanted in the first place.

**Edit** - This solution works, but in my use-case, I need to display an image that is rendered via GL inside the QFrame (specifically, in the viewport within the iPad image we can see here). In Windows, setting the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` property makes that GL-rendered image invisible. It works fine in Mac, though. So I am looking for a solution which will work in Windows as well.

Comment: I don't understand, how would your desired result look like?

Comment: Are you seeing the grey colored background jutting out of the image in all directions? I don't want to see that. Just the image.

Comment: Umm, no, it doesn't. Download it here and check: http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/010/121/original/iPad_Vector.png

Comment: you are right, I just looked at it in firefox which also rendered the transparent border in white/grey

Comment: Yep. So how do I do it? Any idea?

Comment: You could try using `pPainter->drawImage(rect(), QImage(":icon/newskin.png"));` to correctly use the alpha channel of the png image

Comment: Nope. Tried it. Same result. Plus this `paintEvent` way is not sustainable for me, the image will need to change frequently.

Comment: You need to use `QWidget::setMask`. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) for example code.

Comment: QFrame doesn't allow me to set a pixMap, i.e, setPixmap method is not defined for QFrame it seems.

Comment: Please reopen it. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Could you make a bit of photoshop/gimp/paint to post what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Thomas, imagine the image without the grey background jutting out from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works for me (tested under MacOS/X 10.10.3, using Qt 5.5.0-beta; I'd expect it to work under any Qt version 4.5.0 or higher though):

main.h:

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

#include <QFrame>
#include <QPixmap>

class MyFrame : public QFrame
{
public:
   MyFrame(QWidget * parent);

   virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e);

private:
   QPixmap _pixmap;
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include "main.h"

MyFrame :: MyFrame(QWidget * parent) : QFrame(parent, Qt::Window|Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
   setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

   _pixmap.load("/Users/jaf/iPad_Vector.png");
   resize(_pixmap.size());
}

void MyFrame :: paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*e*/)
{
   QPainter p(this);
   p.drawPixmap(0,0,width(),height(), _pixmap);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   MyFrame f(NULL);
   f.show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

Screenshot (showing the app's window in front of my desktop background):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note:  If you need to change to a different pixmap, you can either call _pixmap.load("some_other_image.png") again, and then call update(), or if you want to be more efficient about it, you can have multiple QPixmap member variables loaded at startup and choose the appropriate one to call drawPixmap() with, inside paintEvent(). (Again, call update() to force paintEvent() to be called again)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: By the way, the images look a bit little rough at the corners. Very minute, you have to peer into the screen to spot it, but it's there. The actual image is smooth though. Any way to fix that?

Comment: You could try calling setRenderHint() on your QPainter with various values to see if it makes any difference; I don't know that it will though.

Comment: You are an angel! `QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform` did the trick!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bump this up, but I am having some problem with this method. Not this method per se, it works fine as expected, but in the device viewport we are showing some image that has been rendered via GL. Now calling `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` on the frame renders the image invisible in Windows, and is a known GL issue. Is there any way I can achieve this without using that attribute?

Comment: I doubt it... unless there is a Qt::WA_TranlucentBackgroundThatDoesntBreakOpenGL flag hidden in the Qt headers somewhere... ;)  your best bet is to ask the Qt people to fix their bug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this light modification to your code ?

In case it doesn't work can you publish your compilable code on a public repository ? This would help reproduce in your exact context.

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p)
{
    QPainter* pPainter = new QPainter(this);
    pPainter->setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
    pPainter->drawPixmap(rect(), QPixmap(":icon/newskin.png"));
    delete pPainter;
    QWidget::paintEvent(p);
}
```

Comment: Umm, I will need to change the skin image multiple times. How will this solution work then?

Comment: And by the way, I have already tried it (see the second solution in my question). It gives the same result.

Comment: @Cupidvogel did you see the line with: `pPainter->setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);` ?